# Accidentally overwrote shared files between android project directories with cp -r

Tags: android, unix, gradle, overwrite, cp

I called `cp -r src_directory/ dst_directory/`

I thought that this would copy the src directory and its contents into dst, however, I realized too late that I should have left off the trailing `/`.  Because both directories in question were android projects, they had lots of shared filenames, like build.gradle, local.properties, etc. which are all crucial to building the project.  I also thought that the default behavior would not overwrite clashes, since I used `-r` instead of `-rf`.  Apparently I was mistaken, and all the clashing files were overwritten.

Is there any way to undo this overwrite?  Or am I screwed? Luckily my source files are still saved in the src directory, however, by project will be unable to build without the gradle files.

Comment: consider to check in your code into a version-control system ...the next time.

Comment: if the `dst_directory` was a project maintained by android studio then try `"local history"`

Comment: I just remade the project using src files, it wasn't as hard as I thought.  Thanks though, I didn't know that was a feature of AS.